logback-spring.xml has pattern which I do not want to print if value does not exist
I have logback-spring.xml file with pattern as below
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %level %logger{35}  [%X{dd.trace_id}, %X{dd.span_id}] - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

In logs, it's printing well with [<trace_id>, <span_id>]
but whenever some log statements do not have trace id values since they are not traceable request, it's printing syntax with blank value [,]
In this scenario, I want to print everything omitting [,] from the line.
Thank you.
